# Codelite will not download correctly?

Tags: c, codelite

I am trying to download Codelite on Windows 10 but only downloads as a "7z" file and will not open. I literally have no idea what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: *7z* is an archive format, use a extractor in this case: [Online Extractor](https://extract.me/)...

Answer (score 0):

7z is an [archive file format](https://www.7-zip.org/7z.html) (like zip or rar). For windows you can use for example [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to unpack it.